Combining navigators into one header, putting tabs in a drawer header - React Native, React Navigation
I am looking for a way to combine my nested navigators, my Drawer and my Top Tabs, into one single header. So, to have a drawer button, my tabs, and a settings icon in the same header.
I want it to look something like this:
Combined navigation header
I tried using the headerTitle prop of the Drawer.Screen's option prop, but that just gave me an error:

Error: Another navigator is already registered for this container. You likely have multiple navigators under a single "NavigationContainer" or "Screen". Make sure each navigator is under a separate "Screen" container. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators for a guide on nesting.

There is obviously no way of putting a headerRight or headerLeft, as you would with the Stacked or Drawer navigator headers, on the Tab navigator header.
Does anyone know a way of getting around this? Or making a fully custom Tab navigator the only way, and then populate the headerTitle with it?
